# Styling php/mysql array in a div

Tags: php, html, css, arrays

So I have learned to turn an ordered list output into a div output. 
That was awesome.

My problem is now getting the output of the arrays to stack on top of each other (and side by side with regard to the two divs) like the output would if it was in an ordered list.

The original code was:

```
<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php 
// Run a select query to get my letest 4 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 4");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         $id = $row["id"];
         $product_name = $row["product_name"];
         $price = $row["price"];
         $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
         $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
    <tr>
      <td width="17%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img                   
style="border:#666         1px     solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' .     
$product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></a></td>
      <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
        $' . $price . '<br />
        <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>';
}
} else {
$dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1    
/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>The Shop</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
  <div id="pageContent">
  <table width="85%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
<td width="14%" valign="top"><h3></h3>
  <p><br />
    <br />
    </p></td>
<td width="66%" align="center">
    <h3>The Shop </h3>
  <p><?php echo $dynamicList; ?><br />
    </p>
  <p><br />
  </p></td>
<td width="20%" valign="top"><h3></h3>
    <p></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  </div>
  <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I was given this answer:

```
<?php
  ...
  $dynamicList .= '
  <div id="leftcolumn">
    <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;"     
src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" 
border="1" /></a>
  </div>
  <div id="rightcolumn">' . $product_name . '<br />
    $' . $price . '<br />
    <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a>
  </div>';
  ...
?>

...

<div id="pageContent">
  <h3>The Shop </h3>
  <?php echo $dynamicList; ?>
</div>
```

And this worked great in terms of outputting the lists. 
But the items failed to populate when I added this CSS to the new divs:

```
leftcolumn {
    position: fixed;
    height: 77%;
    width: 18.5%;
    top: 23.8%;
    right: 60.65%;
    bottom: 4.5%;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-top: 2.5%;

}


#rightcolumn {
    position: fixed;
    top: 23.8%;
    padding-top: 2.5%;
    right: 23.5%;
    height: 77%;
    width: 37%;
    bottom: 4.5%;
    background-color: black;  
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the arrays to populate through this CSS styling?
Or what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a class instead of an id.
Like this as your html/php:

```
$dynamicList .= '
    <div class="element">
        <div class="leftcolumn">
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="rightcolumn">
            ' . $product_name . '<br />
            $' . $price . '<br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>';
```

And this for your css:

```
.element {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.leftcolumn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.rightcolumn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Check also this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JrtgL/26/

Comment: Peter, Thank you. That was definitely a step in the right direction. I'm able to populate the items in the divs now. Still, I am unsure why they won't populate vertically in a fixed div...

Comment: You're welcome! It'd be amazing if you could provide a link to a working example so I can help you better with your issue.